# Validating UI against JSON response in RESTAssured/Java

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have a test scenario wherein the fields in my Web application are populated with data from json response.

**e.g**-> there is a field person id which when entered populates dozen other fields in UI ,make certain fields enabled or disabled depending upon other hidden field response in response. 
So, i have to match the json response with the displayed values in UI.
The format of JSON request and response are like name value pair as in below:

```
 {
    "viewcode": 20,
    "actioncode": 40,
    "subcode": 0,
    "errorcode": 5,
    "username": "MANAGER",
    "database": "somedb",
    "data": {
        "personid": "070976",
        "hidden_first": "",
        "hidden_second": "",
        "hidden_third": ""
    }
}
```

I got to know about RestAssured and HTTP client library to achieve this but i am not sure on how to send the request part or retrieve the response because in many cases the responses are very big(more than 150 name value pair).

Below is what i have tried:

```
RestAssured.baseuRL="someurl"

RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given();

Response response=httpRequest.request(Method.POST,"{{"viewcode":20, "actioncode":40, "subcode":0, "errorcode":5, "username":"MANAGER",  "database":"somedb", "data":{ "personid":"070976", "hidden_first":"", "hidden_second":"", "hidden_third":"" }}");

String responseBody=response.getBody.asString();
```

Now, I am getting error in Method.POST line, its showing syntax error also i am confused as to whether there are other approaches or not.

Comment: The question should be tagged with `rest-assured` and `api-testing`. It has nothing to do with `selenium` and `user-interface` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape some symbols (specially `"`):

```
"{\"viewcode\":20, \"actioncode\":40, \"subcode\":0, \"errorcode\":5, \"username\":\"MANAGER\",  \"database\":\"somedb\", \"data\":{ \"personid\":\"070976\", \"hidden_first\":\"\", \"hidden_second\":\"\", \"hidden_third\":\"\" }}"
```

In your code:

```
String json = "{\"viewcode\":20, \"actioncode\":40, \"subcode\":0, \"errorcode\":5, \"username\":\"MANAGER\",  \"database\":\"somedb\", \"data\":{ \"personid\":\"070976\", \"hidden_first\":\"\", \"hidden_second\":\"\", \"hidden_third\":\"\" }}";
httpRequest.body(json);
Response response = httpRequest.post("/replace_with_your_endpoint");
```

A complete list of characters to be escaped can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

Comment: Thanks @Peter, the syntax error are gone now but upon executing the code i get illegalArgument exception:Invalid Number of Parameters: excepted 1 was 0.Undefined parameters are "whatever json request i passed"

Comment: @startedlate what the library are you using for making requests?

Comment: RestAssured 3.1.0